# Efficient way to create list that is function of number of times a string appears in a different list in R

Tags: string, r, list, apply

I have two lists coming from columns in a dataframe (>=300 000 entries), with the first list giving a unique identifier from a data set, and the second list giving linked identifiers taken from the first list, e.g.

```
ids <- list("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6")
linked.ids <- list("a1", "a1", "a3", "a4", "a4", "a4")
```

I need to create a third list (`linked.flag`) to be appended the dataframe that will be blank if the corresponding entry from `linked.ids` has only one match in the list `linked.ids` (i.e. it is only linked with itself), and the entry "Linked" if there is more than one match in the list `linked.ids`. In the above example, the desired outcome would be

I am searching for an efficient way to perform this operation. Here is my current solution:

```
library("stringr")

ids <- c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6")
linked.ids <- c("a1", "a1", "a3", "a4", "a4", "a4")

indices <- 1:length(ids)

count.matches <- function(i1, i2) sum(str_count(linked.ids[i1], linked.ids[i2]))
counts <-sapply(indices, FUN=function(x2) sapply(indices, function(x1) count.matches(x1,x2))) 
counts <- rowSums(counts)

assign.flag <- function(x) if(counts[x] > 1){"Linked"}else{""}
linked.flag <- sapply(indices, FUN=assign.flag)

df <- data.frame(IDs = ids, Links = linked.ids, LinkFlag = linked.flag)
```

which gives as output

```
    IDs Links   LinkFlag
1   a1  a1  Linked
2   a2  a1  Linked
3   a3  a3   
4   a4  a4  Linked
5   a5  a4  Linked
6   a6  a4  Linked
```

My current solution is an adaptation of the accepted answer from [R count times word appears in element of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403196/r-count-times-word-appears-in-element-of-list)

I am relatively new to R, and would be grateful for a more efficient solution (coding style suggestions also appreciated).

Thank you!

Comment: A `data.table` solution: `library(data.table); dt <- data.table(IDs=unlist(ids), Links=unlist(linked.ids), key="Links"); dt[dt[, .N, by=Links][, LinkFlag:=ifelse(N>1, "linked", "")][, list(Links, LinkFlag)]]`. However, I dunno if `ifelse` kills the performance here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ids <- c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6")
linked.ids <- c("a1", "a1", "a3", "a4", "a4", "a4")

count = table(linked.ids) > 1
linked.flag = rep("", length(ids))
linked.flag[linked.ids %in% names(count[count])] = "Linked"
df <- data.frame(IDs = ids, Links = linked.ids, LinkFlag = linked.flag)
```

Comment: Both solutions mentioned thus far are much better than my implementation, but in my actual data set, there were 9 entries (out of 300 000) for which Baumann's solution correctly identified a linked event, while Sven Hohenstein's did not.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to create the data frame:

```
within(data.frame(IDs = unlist(ids),
                  Links = unlist(ids[match(linked.ids, ids)])),
       LinkFlag <- ave(seq_along(Links), Links, FUN = function(x)
         if(length(x) > 1) "Linked" else ""))


  IDs Links LinkFlag
1  a1    a1   Linked
2  a2    a1   Linked
3  a3    a3         
4  a4    a4   Linked
5  a5    a4   Linked
6  a6    a4   Linked
```