# Error when passing objects through apply family functions

Tags: r, lapply, sapply, stringr

Currently getting the error message:

```
 Error in UseMethod("type"):  no applicable method for 'type' applied to an object of class "factor"
```

I'm guessing this is because i am passing the wrong type of object through my function but here is my code:

```
for(i in 1:length(names(testwords))){ allwords <- lapply(testwords[i], function(z) 
count = sapply(df.OE[i], function(x) sum(str_count(x, z))))}
```

Where `testwords` is a list of length 15 and `df.OE` is a dataframe with 2567 observations and 15 variables. Any ideas why this is occurring or even better how i can solve it

For background:
i intend for the for loop to iterate through each list item of testwords (a list of words /terms) and then return the frequency with which these words/ terms occur.

The code i started with was taken from the 2nd part of Julius's answer found here: [R count times word appears in element of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403196/r-count-times-word-appears-in-element-of-list)

Happy to clarify

Thanks,
John

Edit:

This code works:

```
w <- c("a","q","e")
allwords <- lapply(w, function(z)  
            count = sapply(df.OE[1], function(x) sum(str_count(x, z))))
```

So i am assuming the issue is with how pass `testwords` through my code?

Comment: could you give some data so that we can run your code?

Comment: @maRmat managed to solve it by simply wrapping 'as.character' around testwords[l] in the lapply function.